# OAuth2.0 server grant type user credentials password is not encrypted

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am also following what this guy's asking [storage of client credential on OAuth2 server](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/73209/storage-of-client-credential-on-oauth2-server) about [oauth2-server-php-docs](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/73209/storage-of-client-credential-on-oauth2-server/115708). Although it answered one thing for the client secret, I wanna ask about the users credentials. Check the following code sample from [oauth2-server-php-docs](http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/grant-types/user-credentials/):

```
// create some users in memory
$users = array('bshaffer' => array('password' => 'brent123', 'first_name' => 'Brent', 'last_name' => 'Shaffer'));

// create a storage object
$storage = new OAuth2\Storage\Memory(array('user_credentials' => $users));

// create the grant type
$grantType = new OAuth2\GrantType\UserCredentials($storage);

// add the grant type to your OAuth server
$server->addGrantType($grantType);
```

It says that the user credentials will be stored in memory and that it doesn't say anything about password encryption. This is my use case -- I already have user credentials stored in MySQL with password encrypted using PHP password_hash(). So how can I match or use the line $storage = new OAuth2\Storage\Memory() if the $user['bshaffer']['password'] is just a plain text?

Comment: The whole point of oAuth is never needing the user's password. `password_hash` is one-way hashing, not encryption.

Comment: Sorry I should have used the term hash not encryption. However my point was it should not be in plaintext.

Also, why did you say "The whole point of oAuth is never needing the user's password" if there's a choice in the specs to use UserCredentials grant type?

I'm developing an app with entirely decoupled front and back-end. So to make my login as what I'm thinking should be using that grant type.

Comment: @ceejayoz Actually, if you use the 'User Credentials' grant type, then indeed, you will be processing the users password.  This grant type is used when there is a high degree of trust between the client and resource owner. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.3

Answer (score 0):

I have this question too. But if you read the notes in the doc, just below the code snippet you mentioned, it says:

Note: User storage is highly customized for each application, so it is highly recommended you implement your own storage using OAuth2\Storage\UserCredentialsInterface

I think we can implement our own user storage for the users model with the “ OAuth2\Storage\UserCredentialsInterface” interface.

Answer (score -1):

I did this by having my own network architecture and extending the Pdo storage object implementing user-defined password_verify(). So what I did with this one I created mytoken.php that receives the post from the front-end request then sends a request again to 127.0.0.1 to the token.php with the AUTH user and password (client_secret). I did this way so that client_secret is not sent from the front-end request.